# Highlight text without JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not good at JavaScript and I found a snippet in order to highlight text using JQuery Color. It conflicts with Lightbox2 and I want to convert the snippet to JavaScript. Here's my code:

```
function highlight(elemId){
  var elem = $(elemId);
  elem.css("backgroundColor", "#ffffff"); // hack for Safari
  elem.animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffffaa' }, 0);
  setTimeout(function(){$(elemId).animate({ backgroundColor: "#ffffff" }, 3000)},1000);
}

if (document.location.hash) {
  highlight(document.location.hash);
}
$('a[href*="#"]').click(function() {
  var elemId = '#' + $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];
  requestAnimationFrame(highlight(elemId));
});
```

How can I convert the code from JQuery to JavaScript?

Comment: *It conflicts with Lightbox2* - this seems to be your *actual* issue.   *How* does it conflict?  The answer to this determines the fix.   eg if it's because lightbox2 has a `function highlight` then converting `function highlight` to "javascript" will still give your "function highlight" and still have the same conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is all the JavaScript you wanted.

```js
function highlight(elemId) {
  var elem = document.querySelector(elemId);

  // Remove leading #
  elemId = elemId.slice(1);

  // Set initial background color instantly
  elem.style.transition = "background-color 0s";
  elem.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffaa";

  // Trigger reflow
  elem.offsetHeight;

  // Set transition duration for subsequent changes
  elem.style.transition = "background-color 3s";
  elem.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";

  setTimeout(function() {
    elem.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
  }, 1000);
}

if (document.location.hash && document.readyState === 'complete') {
  var elemId = document.location.hash.slice(1); // Remove leading #
  highlight(elemId);
}

document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="#"]').forEach(function(link) {
  link.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var elemId = '#' + this.getAttribute('href').split('#')[1];
    highlight(elemId);
  });
});
```

```html
This is an example<sup><a href="#example">[1]</a></sup> text.<br />
Line 2,<br />
Line 3,<br />
Line 4,<br />
Line 5,<br />
Line 6,<br />
Line 7,<br />
Line 8,<br />
Line 9,<br />
Line 10,<br />
Line 11,<br />
Line 12,<br />
Line 13,<br />
Line 14,<br />
Line 15,<br />
Line 16,<br />
Line 17,<br />
Line 18,<br />
Line 19,<br />
Line 20.<br />
<br />
<p id="example">1: Example; a thing that is typical of or represents a particular group or set.</p>
```

Comment: I'm sorry your snippet doesn't work. Am I missing something? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Now it should work!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need JavaScript if you need to apply *once* a highlight as long as the element is part of the [pseudo-class :target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target)

```css
:target {
  animation: highlight 3s;
}

@keyframes highlight {
  0%   { background: #ffffaa; }
  100% { background: initial; }
}
```

```html
<a href="#foo">Foo</a>
<a href="#bar">Bar</a>

<h2 id="foo">Foo</h2>
<h2 id="bar">Bar</h2>
```

Otherwise, yes, JavaScript can help to achieve the desired goal.
Make sure to use (just like in the example above) a CSS class that will trigger CSS animation by using classList.add and classList.remove once the animation terminates.

```js
const highlight = (selector) => {
  document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(elSelected => {
    elSelected.classList.add("highlight");
    elSelected.addEventListener("animationend", () => {
      elSelected.classList.remove("highlight");
    }, {once: true});
  });
};

document.querySelectorAll(`a[href*="#"]`).forEach(elAnchor => {
  elAnchor.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const selectorId = elAnchor.getAttribute("href").match(/#.+$/)[0];
    highlight(selectorId);
  });
});

// You can also use the function with any selector like:
// highlight("h2");
```

```css
.highlight {
  animation: highlight 3s;
}

@keyframes highlight {
  0%   { background: #ffffaa; }
  100% { background: initial; }
}
```

```html
<a href="#foo">Foo</a>
<a href="#bar">Bar</a>

<h2 id="foo">Foo</h2>
<h2 id="bar">Bar</h2>
```

Find out more about the methods and topics you want to research on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/)